# Accidentally deleted the File Explorer for the Win11 system

Tags: recovery

Has anyone accidentally deleted the File Explorer for the Win11 system? I don't want to reinstall the system to recover it. Could someone who knows a solution please help me?

I tried executing "sfc /SCANNOW" in the command prompt, but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted it? Also, these types of questions are off topic here on Stack Overflow.